# How to sort array of objects based on number of nested sub-childs of objects?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to sort the following array in order on number of sub childs (i.e. number of `ISBN`s in this case).

```
const data = [{
      "Arnold Bennett": {
         "9781784872359": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/571b8c01-ed88-4cc1-8e0c-efe3de967147.jpg",
            "title": "Clayhanger "
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "Agatha Christie": {
         "9780007527588": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=BxlamwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Mrs. McGinty's Dead"
         },
         "9780008129590": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/c125ee1d-c5ea-4827-a488-e9ee9c8afc8d.jpg",
            "title": "The Clocks"
         },
         "9780007120857": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=RAlvswEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Murder at the Vicarage"
         },
         "9780007556878": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Zb_inQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Dead Man's Folly"
         },
         "9780007120826": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Dve45zlLKbUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "4.50 from Paddington"
         },
         "9780007121052": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=QR9J95ZE2zcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Nemesis"
         },
         "9780007527519": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=dOrsAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Five Little Pigs"
         },
         "9780007120963": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/ba1fcb40-5383-40d9-bdfc-0e9d285b2321.jpeg",
            "title": "A Murder is Announced "
         },
         "9780008196233": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/3a08b20a-377e-4b96-890c-1ecc3e09e595.jpg",
            "title": "The Sittaford Mystery"
         },
         "9780008196615": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=6E8FvgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "At Bertram's Hotel"
         },
         "9780008129484": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fe46e96d-7f24-40f1-92e1-b60f10af9dd1.jpg",
            "title": "The Mystery of the Blue Train"
         },
         "9780007314669": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/cd40bc91-4c28-4f97-872a-ba24f10b0564.jpg",
            "title": "An Autobiography"
         },
         "9780006513773": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JMqChKyf-0EC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Hercule Poirot"
         },
         "9780007527502": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=9CO1mgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Murder on the Orient Express"
         },
         "9780007527496": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ERPosgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Mysterious Affair at Styles"
         },
         "9780007120833": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=lA1KuAEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Body in the Library"
         },
         "9780007120734": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=CEEUPYluIeEC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Five Little Pigs"
         },
         "9780007120970": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fd1f1d09-c08f-4f35-8be1-a35862d9e4b6.jpg",
            "title": "A Pocket Full of Rye"
         },
         "9780007120864": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=MK9JNwoZAncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Thirteen Problems"
         },
         "9780008125929": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=kxK7rQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Secret Adversary (隱身魔鬼)"
         },
         "9780007121069": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ddlQBfuKWzwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Sleeping Murder"
         },
         "9780008164898": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JCX2sgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Cards on the Table"
         }
      }
   }, {
      "Alain De Botton": {
         "9780141035192": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=l4FGPwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Consolations of Philosophy"
         }
      }
   }, {
      "Alan Hollinghurst": {
         "9781447275183": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/b46fc3f6-4950-4e4d-a734-93abd10b5351.jpeg",
            "title": "The Line of Beauty"
         }
      }
   }, {
      "Alan MacDonald": {
         "9781407108315": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=1aEGOwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Winston Churchill and His Woeful Wars"
         }
      }
   }, {
      "Aldous Huxley": {
         "9780099518471": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3zl4oJMUskoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "Brave New World"
         }
      }
   }, {
      "Alessandro Manzoni": {
         "9780140442748": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=azLiQUtMSncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Betrothed"
         },
         "9780241259078": {
            "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=nyo8jwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
            "title": "The Betrothed"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I want to sort so that I get `Agatha Christie` on top and then `Alessandro Manzoni` and then the rest of them in order of child elements they have.

Thanks

Comment: `data:[
{
    {
        " Arnold Bennett": {` Invalid syntax

Comment: I tried the following - data.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
            // Ascending: first age less than the previous
            return Object.keys(obj1).length - Object.keys(obj2).length;
        });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) , [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const data=[{" Arnold Bennett":{"9781784872359":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/571b8c01-ed88-4cc1-8e0c-efe3de967147.jpg","title":"Clayhanger "}}},{"Agatha Christie":{"9780007527588":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=BxlamwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Mrs. McGinty's Dead"},"9780008129590":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/c125ee1d-c5ea-4827-a488-e9ee9c8afc8d.jpg","title":"The Clocks"},"9780007120857":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=RAlvswEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Murder at the Vicarage"},"9780007556878":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Zb_inQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Dead Man's Folly"},"9780007120826":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Dve45zlLKbUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"4.50 from Paddington"},"9780007121052":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=QR9J95ZE2zcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Nemesis"},"9780007527519":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=dOrsAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Five Little Pigs"},"9780007120963":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/ba1fcb40-5383-40d9-bdfc-0e9d285b2321.jpeg","title":"A Murder is Announced "},"9780008196233":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/3a08b20a-377e-4b96-890c-1ecc3e09e595.jpg","title":"The Sittaford Mystery"},"9780008196615":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=6E8FvgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"At Bertram's Hotel"},"9780008129484":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fe46e96d-7f24-40f1-92e1-b60f10af9dd1.jpg","title":"The Mystery of the Blue Train"},"9780007314669":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/cd40bc91-4c28-4f97-872a-ba24f10b0564.jpg","title":"An Autobiography"},"9780006513773":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JMqChKyf-0EC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Hercule Poirot"},"9780007527502":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=9CO1mgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Murder on the Orient Express"},"9780007527496":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ERPosgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Mysterious Affair at Styles"},"9780007120833":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=lA1KuAEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Body in the Library"},"9780007120734":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=CEEUPYluIeEC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Five Little Pigs"},"9780007120970":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fd1f1d09-c08f-4f35-8be1-a35862d9e4b6.jpg","title":"A Pocket Full of Rye"},"9780007120864":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=MK9JNwoZAncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"The Thirteen Problems"},"9780008125929":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=kxK7rQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Secret Adversary (隱身魔鬼)"},"9780007121069":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ddlQBfuKWzwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Sleeping Murder"},"9780008164898":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JCX2sgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Cards on the Table"}}},{"Alain De Botton":{"9780141035192":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=l4FGPwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Consolations of Philosophy"}}},{"Alan Hollinghurst":{"9781447275183":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/b46fc3f6-4950-4e4d-a734-93abd10b5351.jpeg","title":"The Line of Beauty"}}},{"Alan MacDonald":{"9781407108315":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=1aEGOwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Winston Churchill and His Woeful Wars"}}},{"Aldous Huxley":{"9780099518471":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3zl4oJMUskoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Brave New World"}}},{"Alessandro Manzoni":{"9780140442748":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=azLiQUtMSncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"The Betrothed"},"9780241259078":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=nyo8jwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Betrothed"}}}]

data.sort((a,b) => {
  return Object.keys(Object.values(b)[0]).length - Object.keys(Object.values(a)[0]).length
})

console.log(data)
```

`Object.values(b)[0]` returns

```
{
  "9781407108315": {
    "thumbnail_image_url": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=1aEGOwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api",
    "title": "Winston Churchill and His Woeful Wars"
  }
}
```

Then count how many `keys` this object has using `Object.keys`

Comment: Perfect! thanks, I was messing with the same idea, but was doing it completly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the values for each object, since your top-most object only hold the author, you index the values array at 0, which will give you the object under the author.

From this object, you then count the keys, which are the ISBN numbers:

```js
const data = [{"Arnold Bennett":{"9781784872359":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/571b8c01-ed88-4cc1-8e0c-efe3de967147.jpg","title":"Clayhanger "}}},{"Agatha Christie":{"9780007527588":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=BxlamwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Mrs. McGinty's Dead"},"9780008129590":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/c125ee1d-c5ea-4827-a488-e9ee9c8afc8d.jpg","title":"The Clocks"},"9780007120857":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=RAlvswEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Murder at the Vicarage"},"9780007556878":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Zb_inQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Dead Man's Folly"},"9780007120826":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Dve45zlLKbUC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"4.50 from Paddington"},"9780007121052":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=QR9J95ZE2zcC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Nemesis"},"9780007527519":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=dOrsAQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Five Little Pigs"},"9780007120963":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/ba1fcb40-5383-40d9-bdfc-0e9d285b2321.jpeg","title":"A Murder is Announced "},"9780008196233":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/3a08b20a-377e-4b96-890c-1ecc3e09e595.jpg","title":"The Sittaford Mystery"},"9780008196615":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=6E8FvgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"At Bertram's Hotel"},"9780008129484":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fe46e96d-7f24-40f1-92e1-b60f10af9dd1.jpg","title":"The Mystery of the Blue Train"},"9780007314669":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/cd40bc91-4c28-4f97-872a-ba24f10b0564.jpg","title":"An Autobiography"},"9780006513773":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JMqChKyf-0EC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Hercule Poirot"},"9780007527502":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=9CO1mgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Murder on the Orient Express"},"9780007527496":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ERPosgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Mysterious Affair at Styles"},"9780007120833":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=lA1KuAEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Body in the Library"},"9780007120734":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=CEEUPYluIeEC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Five Little Pigs"},"9780007120970":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/fd1f1d09-c08f-4f35-8be1-a35862d9e4b6.jpg","title":"A Pocket Full of Rye"},"9780007120864":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=MK9JNwoZAncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"The Thirteen Problems"},"9780008125929":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=kxK7rQEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Secret Adversary (隱身魔鬼)"},"9780007121069":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=ddlQBfuKWzwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Sleeping Murder"},"9780008164898":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=JCX2sgEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Cards on the Table"}}},{"Alain De Botton":{"9780141035192":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=l4FGPwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Consolations of Philosophy"}}},{"Alan Hollinghurst":{"9781447275183":{"thumbnail_image_url":"https://books-sn.s3.amazonaws.com/b46fc3f6-4950-4e4d-a734-93abd10b5351.jpeg","title":"The Line of Beauty"}}},{"Alan MacDonald":{"9781407108315":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=1aEGOwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"Winston Churchill and His Woeful Wars"}}},{"Aldous Huxley":{"9780099518471":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3zl4oJMUskoC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"Brave New World"}}},{"Alessandro Manzoni":{"9780140442748":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=azLiQUtMSncC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api","title":"The Betrothed"},"9780241259078":{"thumbnail_image_url":"http://books.google.com/books/content?id=nyo8jwEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api","title":"The Betrothed"}}}];

const countISBNs = entry => Object.keys(Object.values(entry)[0]).length;

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => countISBNs(b) - countISBNs(a));

console.log(sorted);
```